# What are the limits of converting int to real

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, casting

When I write:

`SELECT CAST (CAST (32652317 as real) as int)`

The result is:

```
32652316
```

What is the maximum integer number to be safely stored within a column of type `real` without a risk of getting wrong value?

Comment: With `REAL` or `FLOAT` there's always a risk of not *wrong* but sometimes *unexpected* results... Do you have a good reason to use `REAL`?

Comment: @Shnugo - Do we have to worry about the Integer part also ?

Comment: @Shungo I need to minimize storage space & most values are low with 2 decimals, but some are bigger integers

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal well, in most cases numbers need to be exact. With `REAL` you never know what you get... Btw: If my answer solves your initial question, it would be nice to accept it. Thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for fun:

The following code will return the first number, where your cast and the original number are different.

```
WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
    ,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
    ,Tally AS(SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))) AS Nr FROM N3 
              CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
SELECT TOP 1 Nr,CAST (CAST (Tally.Nr AS REAL) AS INT)
FROM Tally
WHERE Nr<>CAST (CAST (Tally.Nr AS REAL) AS INT);
```

My result was `16777217 and 16777216`

## UPDATE

With higher numbers the difference increases. The following looks for the first where the differenc is higher than 2:

```
WITH x AS(SELECT 1 AS N FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1)) AS tbl(N))--10^1
    ,N3 AS (SELECT 1 AS N FROM x CROSS JOIN x AS N2 CROSS JOIN x N3) --10^3
    ,Tally AS(SELECT (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY(SELECT NULL))) AS Nr FROM N3 
              CROSS JOIN N3 N6 CROSS JOIN N3 AS N9)
SELECT TOP 1 Nr,CAST (CAST (Tally.Nr AS REAL) AS INT)
FROM Tally
WHERE ABS(Nr-CAST (CAST (Tally.Nr AS REAL) AS INT))>2
```

My result was `67,108,867   and 67,108,864`

Asked for *`>5`* I got `134,217,734 and 134,217,728`

### UPDATE: Float vs. Real

If you replace the `REAL` with `FLOAT`, there won't be any allowed INT which breaks your cast, but this takes 8 byte storage.

According to [this page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173773.aspx) `REAL` is treated as `FLOAT(24)` taking 4 bytes. 24 of 32 bits are used for the mantissa. `FLOAT` expects an `INT`-parameter to set its width.  `FLOAT(24)` is far below the max width. Omitting this parameter is defaulted with the max value 53, but taking 8 bytes.

Even with `FLOAT(1)` at least 1 bit is reserved for the mantissa. When the 7th byte is "begun", the rounding begins. This happens 1 number below 16777217:

[image: Byte 7 is begun]

Comment: Great... Never know this

Comment: So real can safely store only three byte integers up to 16777215 (0xFFFFFF) because exponent takes 8 bites according to IEEE 754 single?

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal How many rows are there? You said: *most values are low with 2 decimals, but some are bigger integers*. What is the biggest int number you expect, what the lowest? Try with `DECIMAL(10,2)`. This will stay within 8 byte storage up to 42,949,672. (Empirically tested with `DATALENGTH`)

Comment: @Shungo There will be millions of rows soon. That is why I would like to stick with 4 bytes real. The interger values are weights in kgs per 120 seconds on a conveyor belt, so it is not a very exact number of cca max 100 000, so it should be ok.

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal Well, to be honest: I would not bother about disc storage! Especially with many rows you will have **much bigger troubles** if you try to trick around just for saving storage space later. Using appropriate data types is worth it in almost all cases. I'd stick with `DECIMAL(X,2)` (with X set big enough for your needs).

Comment: @VojtěchDohnal just do some calculations... Even with 10 millions of rows you are thinking about 40mio byte or 80mio byte. This difference is in most cases of no importance at all... Not much more than a few Hi-Res photographs